# How to add polylines to Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Maps API. I am trying to add polylines and the coordinates from a database. Can anyone tell me how to use marker manager to add polylines? I think I have too many coordinates and it is getting messy. Using a marker manager may help. Any suggestions?
The code I am using is:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$truckCount;$i++)
            {
                $j=0;
        $k=1;
                do
                {
                    $data = pg_fetch_row($result,$j);
            $data1=pg_fetch_row($result,$k);
                    $j++;
            $k++;
                }while(condition)
                echo"points[$i]=[new GLatLng($data[4], $data[5]),new GLatLng($data1[4], $data1[5])];";
        echo"polyline= new GPolyline(points,'#0000FF', 6, 0.5);";
        echo "setTimeout(function() {map.addOverlay(polyline);},2);";

            }
```

I used GLog.write(points) and I see that only first two coordinates get passed hence no line is plotted

Comment: this part is in php, as I was retrieving coordinated from database

Comment: till data is a variable which I calculate by  " pg_num_rows($result)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the new GPolyline part outside the loop.  So you're adding each individual coordinate into your array, then at the end you use that whole array to create the polyline.

```
for(i=0;i<till data;i++)
{
  $data=pg_fetch_row($result,$i);
  points[$i]= new GLatLng($data[4],$data[5]); // Lat,Long coordinates are at 5th and 6th column
}

var polyline = new GPolyline(points,color,4,1);
map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

**Update:** alternatively, if you're wanting to draw each segment of the line one at a time, you could try creating a new array that will only ever have 2 coordinates: the start point and end point for an individual segment.  You need to loop until array.length-1 this time (not sure how you need to modify your PHP array, so I'll write up something in pure Javascript syntax instead - you'll need to modify back to PHP)

```
var coordinates = // your data array;
var points,polyline;

for(i=0;i < coordinates.length-1; i++) {
  // recreate the array
  points = [];

  // add the first coordinate
  points[0]= new GLatLng(coordinates[i].lat,coordinates[i].lon); 

  // add the 2nd coordinate
  points[1]= new GLatLng(coordinates[i+1].lat,coordinates[i+1].lon);

  polyline = new GPolyline(points,color,4,1);
  map.addOverlay(polyline);

  // at this point here you could add a setTimeout if still required
}
```

Comment: I did that, but as I have a lot of co ordinates, It just messes up a lot and reduces the efficiency significantly. Is there a better way to do it. Can I delay plotting of individual lines, like one tenth of a second. I tried using "setTimeout"  but that just delays and still plots it all together

Comment: can you please see my answer to figure out what might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code to add lines one by one

for($i=0; $i<2000; $i++)

```
            {
                $data1 = pg_fetch_row($result,$i);
                $data2 = pg_fetch_row($result,$i+1);
                echo "points[$i] = newGLatLng($data1[4], $data1[5]);\n";
                echo "points[$i+1] = newGLatLng($data2[4],$data2[5]);\n";
                echo" var polyline = new GPolyline(points,'#0000FF', 6, 0.5);";
                echo "setTimeout(function() {map.addOverlay(polyline);},2);";

                }
```

Comment: I am not getting any of those errors, The page loads, every other marker gets placed but the polylines

Comment: can you add an alert or console.log() inside your setTimeout function to ensure that it is getting called

Comment: @duncan  I added Glog.write. And I see that no coordinates are being passed to the variable "points".  Can I send you my source code?

Comment: go ahead (you should be able to see it on my profile page) although you'd be better to post as much of that as you can in your original question.

Comment: @duncan  I could not see on you profile to how to go ahead send my source code

Comment: I couldn't see what the problem was

Comment: @ duncan  Whenever I try to add an extra variable array, to hold the value for second consecutive coordinate(to  make sure at each point we have just two coordinates) , It displays an error and the function does not proceed

Comment: @duncan I updated my code and was able to get the desired coordinates. now I am using the code in the above answer to plot the lines, but still it gets plotted all at once rather than being plotted one by one